# How do fix this function to make it not show "None" at the bottom?

Tags: python, nonetype

So right now this function returns the results I want but there is an annoying "None" at the very bottom. I understand this is because there is nothing to return that's why "None" is printed, but how can I change up my code to show the results without the "None"?

Thanks. Also, the "print(steps(6))" line is mandatory as it is part of an exercise.

```
def steps(i):
    t = 0
    for i in range(1, i + 1):
        print(("\t" * t) + (str(i) * 3) + "\n")
        t += 1

print(steps(6))
```

And the result is

```
111

    222

        333

            444

                555

                    666

None #I want to get rid of this.
```

Comment: remove `print()` from `print(steps(6))`. Since your `steps()` method is not returning anything and does all the printing work in its body, so there is no need of using `print(steps(6))`

Answer (score 1):

Functions return `None` by default; by calling `print(function)`, you are printing the returned value, in your case, it is `None`.
Because the printing happens in your function, you could call `steps` without printing:

#### Edit:

if the print is mandatory... Maybe you could return the empty string then:

```
def steps(i):
    t = 0
    for i in range(1, i + 1):
        print(("\t" * t) + (str(i) * 3) + "\n")
        t += 1
    return ''

print(steps(6))
```

#### output:

```
111

    222

        333

            444

                555

                    666
''
```

Comment: Hi Reblochon, thanks for the lighting response. But the bottom print is mandatory and I can't modify it.

Answer (score 1):

You Should remove print

```
def steps(i):
    t = 0
    for i in range(1, i + 1):
        print(("\t" * t) + (str(i) * 3) + "\n")
        t += 1



steps(6)
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your code like this:

```
def steps(i):
    t = 0
    for i in range(1, i + 1):
        print(("\t" * t) + (str(i) * 3) + "\n")
        t += 1
    return "" #updated
print(steps(6)) #Now your print function will get the value "" (empty string), and will print it
```

When your function does not explicitly return any value then it returns the default return value `None`. Your `print` function is getting this `None` and printing it.
Output:

```
111

    222

        333

            444

                555

                    666
```

Comment: Hi Taohidul, thanks for the lighting response. But the bottom print is mandatory and I can't modify it.

Comment: Then you can return an empty value at the end of your code like `return ""`

Comment: Why downvoting?

Comment: We tested your code with num_steps = 3. We expected steps to return the str 
"111
 222
  333
". However, it returned the str "".

So weird.

Comment: I have tested it again, it generates expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this code

```
print str(10)
```

Simple right! the result is "10". So what is it going inside this snippet?
str(10) takes an object as input and return a string as output. So print operator takes a string as input and prints it in the STD output file. 
So what about None return type function. (i.e Void return function), and that's what exactly happened in your code.
The correct code is

```
def steps(i):
    t = 0
    for i in range(1, i + 1):
        print(("\t" * t) + (str(i) * 3) + "\n")
        t += 1
    return '' 
print(steps(6))
```

or

```
def steps(i):
    t = 0
    for i in range(1, i + 1):
        print(("\t" * t) + (str(i) * 3) + "\n")
        t += 1

steps(6)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def steps(i):
        t = 0
        for i in range(1, i + 1):
             print(("\t" * t) + (str(i) * 3) + "\n")
             t += 1
        return ""
steps(6)
```

Please remove print from `steps(6)` then you will get rid off `None`.